# How to replace double quotes in headers and rows in a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, java-11, csvreader, csvwriter

I'm new to Java. I have the following CSV file located in my local folder: `C:\Users\MyFile\myFile.csv`. The first line of the file is the header. I would like to replace the double quotes from headers and values in the file and replace the file in the same location. I used this code [how to remove double quotes while reading CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079093/how-to-remove-double-quotes-while-reading-csv) to mimic the logic, but couldn't succeed.

Actual `myFile.csv` (sample records):

```
"ID","EMAIL","FIRSTNAME","LASTNAME"             
 99999,"TestEmail@fakeemail.com","TEST_FNAME","TEST_LNAME"
 33333,"TestEmail@fakeemail.com","ACTV","TEST_FNAME","TEST_LNAME"
```

Expected `myFile.csv` (sample records):

```
ID,EMAIL,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME             
99999,TestEmail@fakeemail.com,TEST_FNAME,TEST_LNAME
33333,TestEmail@fakeemail.com,ACTV,TEST_FNAME,TEST_LNAME
```

Comment: The library you're using should be able to output the CSV without those unnecessary double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the contents, remove quotes, write back:

```
String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
contents = contents.replace("\"", "");
Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), contents.getBytes());
```

---

Of course, you can do this in one line:

```
Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName))).replace("\"", "").getBytes());
```

Comment: @stdunbar It worked for all the rows and columns.